# Parent row and child Column Layout Breaks in IE11 but works in other browsers

Tags: angular-flex-layout

When I use fxLayout="row" in parent div and fxLayout="column" in child div
its getting collapsed or overlapped in IE 11, but works in other browsers

kindly refer the stackbliz link for the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcmerb

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="none" fxFlex="1 1 auto">
          <div class="offer-text" fxLayout="column">
            <div class="m-b-15 text-14">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
            <div  class="martop-20" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end end" fxFlex="1 1 auto">
             Condition Apply
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing so many combination this one worked for me, posting here so that it will be help full for other person

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="none" fxFlex="1 1 auto">
          <div class="offer-text" fxLayout="column">
```

replace the above code with the below one it, will work in all the browsers if you are looking for even structure, for the bottom text in Angular flex layout

```
   <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="none" fxFlex="1 1 auto">
```